# mongodb return _id field as id string instead of ObjectID

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

How can I create a mongo query which returns the `_id` field as `id` and stringified.

Given this code

```
const _id = new ObjectId(id)
const event = await db.collection('events').findOne({ _id })
```

How can I produce this output

```
event = { id: 644289148310cef91729d97c, name: 'Event Name' }
```

Instead of the current output

```
event = { id: ObjectId("644289148310cef91729d97c"), name: 'Event Name' }
```

I would like to do this as part of a mongo query instead of iterating over the returned objects in javscript.

I am using the `mongodb` library, NOT mongoose.

Comment: You can use projection `{ _id: 0, id: { $convert: { input: "$_id", to: "string"} }, event: 1 }` to change the output.

Comment: `const event = await db.collection('events').findOne({ _id },{_id: 0, id:{$toString: "$_id"}})`

Comment: btw in nodejs driver projection is like `findOne({ _id },{projection:{_id:0,....}})` iirc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using `projection` and `$toString`.

```
const event = await db()
    .collection('events')
    .findOne(
        { _id },
        { 
            projection: {
                _id: 0,
                id: {$toString: "$_id" },
                name: 1,
            }
        }
    )
```